# If $\frac{P(E_n)}{P(F_n)} \to 1$, does $\frac{P(A \cap F_n)}{P(A \cap E_n)} \to 1$?

Tags: real-analysis, probability

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal F, P)$ be a probability space. Let $E_1\supset E_2\supset ...$ and $F_1 \supset F_2 \supset...$ be two decreasing sequences of events in $\mathcal F$ with the following properties.

1. $E_n \subset F_n$.
2. $\bigcap_n E_n  = \bigcap_n F_n \neq \emptyset$.
3. $P(E_n) > 0$.

Let $A \in \mathcal F$. Let's assume in addition that

4. $P(A \cap E_n)>0$.

**Question.** If $P(E_n)/P(F_n) \to 1$, does $P(A \cap F_n)/P(A \cap E_n) \to 1$ as well?

The answer is obviously yes if $P(A \cap \bigcap_nE_n)>0$, so we can assume this isn't the case.

Heuristically, it seems to me that the answer should be yes: $P(F_n)$ and $P(E_n)$ are decreasing to the same limit at the same rate and $P(A \cap E_n)$ and $P(A \cap F_n)$ are decreasing to the same limit. I can't see why intersecting with a single set $A$ would change the rates of convergence, so it seems like the result should hold.

I think I'm just missing an easy algebraic trick or something like that, however, because I haven't been able to prove this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

###### Beginning thoughts

It is nice if I can work out this problem , starting from how I thought about it when I first saw it, to how I decided to attack it and how I succeeded. Having a methodical approach to problems can be very beneficial.

In this case, I know that $E_n \subset F_n$ and that $\frac{P(F_n)}{P(E_n)} \to 1$ (you've written this as $\frac{P(E_n)}{P(F_n)} \to 1$ but what I write is clearly equivalent by continuity of the function $\frac 1x$ at the point $1$).

Now we write $$
\frac{P(A \cap F_n)}{P(A \cap E_n)} = \frac{P(A \cap (E_n \cup(F_n \setminus E_n)))}{P(A \cap E_n)} = \frac{P(A \cap E_n)+P(A \cap (F_n \setminus E_n))}{P(A \cap E_n)}\\ = 1+\frac{P(A \cap (F_n \setminus E_n))}{P(A \cap E_n)}
$$

Rewriting this, $$
\frac{P(A \cap F_n)}{P(A \cap E_n)} - 1 = \frac{P(A \cap (F_n \setminus E_n))}{P(A \cap E_n)}
$$

We'd love it if that went to zero. In a very similar way we get $$
\frac{P(F_n)}{P(E_n)} - 1 = \frac{P(F_n \setminus E_n)}{P(E_n)} \to 0
$$
which is true by hypothesis.

(*Edited to include details*)

Now ,suppose as a hunch that I wanted to prove that $\frac{P(A \cap (F_n \setminus E_n))}{P(A \cap E_n)} \to 0$. Clearly, the only available way to do this right now would be to *compare it* to $\frac{P(F_n \setminus E_n)}{P(E_n)}$ which is a quantity going to $0$ as well.

Now, clearly $P(A \cap (F_n \setminus E_n)) \leq P(F_n \setminus E_n)$ which goes to zero. Therefore, the numerator of one beats the numerator of the other.

We claim that if $P(A \cap E_n) \to c >0$ , then we can apply the ratio theorem to conclude. Indeed, If this is the case, then $P(E_n)$ also converges to some limit $c'>c>0$, and then $\frac{P(A \cap E_n)}{P(E_n)} \to \frac{c}{c'}$. Now note that $$
\frac{\frac{P(A \cap (F_n \setminus E_n))}{P(A \cap E_n)}}{\frac{P(F_n \setminus E_n)}{P(E_n)}} = \frac{P(A \cap (F_n \setminus E_n))}{P(F_n \setminus E_n)}\frac{P(E_n)}{P(A \cap E_n)} \leq \frac{P(E_n)}{P(A \cap E_n)} \leq \frac{c'}{c}+1
$$
for large enough $n$. It follows by the squeeze theorem that $\frac{P(A \cap (F_n \setminus E_n))}{P(A \cap E_n)} \to 0$, which is a positive result.

Now, the question is : what if $P(A \cap E_n) \to 0$? In that case, the quantity $\frac{c'}{c}$ will not be a finite quantity since $c=0$. Can we somehow work around this?

That is, the truth of the result now hinges upon whether $P(A \cap E_n)$ and $P(E_n)$ are comparable even if $P(A \cap E_n)\to 0$, so that we can use the squeeze theorem to complete the result. If you notice, what we required exactly was that $\frac{P(E_n)}{P(A \cap E_n)}< C$ for some constant $C$ independent of $n$ for large enough $n$.

Now we notice the problem : the hypothesis clearly don't say enough about $A$ to ensure that $P(A \cap E_n)$ is *not much smaller than $E_n$*. In fact, *it is possible that* $\frac{P(A \cap E_n)}{P(E_n)} \to 0$ and such a situation is quite easy to create : it does not take a great mind to find the right example.

---

###### The $A$ and $E_n$

We will stick to the Lebesgue measure on $[0,1]$ with the Borel sigma-algebra.

Suppose that $A = [0.25,0.75]$. Let $E_n = [0.25-\frac{1}{8n}, 0.25+\frac 1{8n^2}] \cup [0.75 - \frac 1{8n^2},0.75 + \frac 1{8n}]$. It's clear that $P(E_n) = 2(\frac 1{8n}+ \frac 1{8n^2}) = \frac 1{4n} + \frac 1{4n^2}$. On the other hand, $P(E_n \cap A) = 2 \times \frac 1{8n^2} = \frac 1{4n^2}$. Clearly, $\frac{P(A \cap E_n)}{P(E_n)} \to 0$. Furthermore, by simply making the $\frac 1{8n^2}$ to $\frac 1{8n^3}$ or something stronger, we can make this ratio decay *as fast as we like*!

(Perhaps this is not the most obvious example, I'll leave others to find better ones, but it works)

The $E_n$ and $A$ satisfy all the conditions : they are Borel sets, $P(E_n) >0, \cap_{n \geq 1} E_n \neq \emptyset$ because it contains both $0.25$ and $0.75$, and $P(A \cap E_n) >0$ as well. All that's left to do is design the $F_n$ carefully.

---

###### The $F_n$

The $F_n$ should be such that

- $P(F_n)\to 0$ at the same rate as $P(E_n)$, so that is at the rate $\frac{1}{4n}$.
- $P(A \cap (F_n \setminus E_n))$ and $P(A \cap E_n)$ should be of the same order.

Here's the answer : simply extend $E_n$ a little more into the interior of $A$ to create $F_n$, and if necessary, to the exterior as well. Keep it flexible : suppose that $a_n,b_n$ are two non-negative sequences of real numbers and let $F_n = [0.25 - \frac{1}{8n}-a_n,0.25+\frac 1{8n^2}+b_n] \cup [0.75 - \frac{1}{8n^2}-b_n,0.25+\frac 1{8n^2}+a_n]$ where $a_n,b_n$ are chosen such that $\frac 1{8n^2}+b_n\leq 0.25, \frac 1{8n} + a_n \leq 0.25$ for all $n \geq 1$. This ensures that $F_n \subset [0,1]$ is the union of two intervals.

Then, we notice that $E_n \subset F_n$ and

- $P(F_n \setminus E_n) = 2a_n+2b_n$, so $a_n+b_n \to 0$ must happen.
- $P(A \cap (F_n \setminus E_n)) = 2b_n$ should grow at least as fast as $P(A \cap E_n) = \frac 1{4n^2}$.

But now, the answer is obvious : simply pick $b_n = \frac 1{8n^2}$ and $a_n = 0$ for all $n$. We then get that $P(A \cap (F_n \setminus E_n)) = \frac 1{8n^2} + \frac 1{8n^2} = \frac 1{4n^2}$ has the same growth rate as $P(A \cap E_n) = \frac 1{4n^2}$. Therefore, $$
\frac{P(A \cap (F_n \setminus E_n))}{P(A \cap E_n)} \to 1 \implies \frac{P(A \cap F_n)}{P(A \cap E_n)} \to 2
$$
a contradiction.

Let's check all the conditions again, while writing down the sets in question.

- $E_n = [0.25 - \frac 1{8n},0.25+\frac 1{8n^2}] \cup [0.75 - \frac 1{8n^2},0.75+\frac 1{8n}]$.
- $F_n = [0.25 - \frac 1{8n},0.25+\frac 1{4n^2}] \cup [0.75 - \frac 1{4n^2},0.75+\frac 1{8n}]$
- $A = [0.25,0.75]$.

Then,

- $E_n,F_n,A \in \mathcal F$ is obvious.
- $E_n \subset F_n$ is true.
- $\cap_{n} E_n = \cap_{n} F_n = \{0.25,0.75\} \neq \emptyset$.
- $P(E_n) = \frac 1{4n}+\frac 1{4n^2} > 0$.
- $P(A\cap E_n) = \frac 1{4n^2} > 0$.
- $P(F_n) = \frac 1{4n}+\frac 1{2n^2}$, hence $\frac{P(F_n)}{P(E_n)} \to 1$.
- $P(A \cap F_n) = \frac 1{2n^2}$, so that $\frac{P(A \cap F_n)}{P(A \cap E_n)} \to 2$.

Therefore, we have a counterexample to the question.

Perhaps the key insight in solving this question is the recognition that $P(A \cap E_n)$ can have little to no asymptotic relation with $P(E_n)$.

###### Addendum

I also leave an interested reader to prove that one can modify the above construction of $F_n,E_n$ , leaving $A$ the same, to actually get that $\frac{P(A \cap F_n)}{P(A \cap E_n)}$ can go to infinity, faster than any given function (say, a polynomial of $n$). All one needs to do is recognize that the $\frac 1n$ part of $E$ and $F$ outside $A$ ensures that $\frac{P(F_n)}{P(E_n)} \to 1$, and then one merely adjusts the intersections with $A$ carefully , making the intersection $E _n\cap A$ really really small and making $P(F_n \cap A)$ much larger but smaller in order than $P(F_n)$ itself.

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful, but I don't follow some of your remarks in the first half. Suppose $P(A \cap E_n)/P(A_n)$ converged to a limit in $[0,1]$. Are you saying then the squeeze theorem would get the result? How would that work?

Comment: @aduh I will edit my post in about an hour's time since I couldnot finish my edit before lunch. I wasn't quite as precise as I could be there, so I will expand on it and revamp the answer.

Comment: @aduh I edited the answer.

Answer (score 1):

If

$$P(E_n \cap A) = 2^{-(n+2)}$$

$$P(F_n \cap A) = 2^{-(n+1)}$$

$$P(E_n \cap A^c)=P(F_n \cap A^c) = \frac{1}{2}$$

Then
$$P(E_n \cap A)/P(F_n \cap A) \to \frac{1}{2}$$
So you can construct a counterexample like this.

For example, consider the uniform distribution on $[0,1]$ and let $E_n$ be the event that $X>\frac{1}{2}$ or the first $n+2$ digits of $X$ in binary are 0. Let $F_n$ be the event that $X>\frac{1}{2}$ or the first $n+1$ digits of $X$ in binary are 0. Where $A$ is the event $X \le \frac{1}{2}$

Comment: Do there exist such $E_n,F_n,A$ so that this holds?

Comment: @Snoop I made a crucial mistake, it should have said $E_n \cap A^c$ etc. I have fixed it now and given an example.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't get what 'the first [...] digits in binary' means nor I see a specification of $A$.

Comment: @Snoop It means the first $k$ digits after the decimal place are 0. It's just the same as $X<2^{-k}$.

Comment: So $P(E_n\cap A^c) = P(\{X<2^{-(n+2)}\}\cap \{X\leq 1/2\})\stackrel{?}{=}1/2$?

Comment: I really want to upvote one of the concise answers here but I need some clarity before doing that. Pardon my pedantic questions!

Comment: @snoop I'm so sorry I made another stupid mistake. $A$ should be the event $X \le \frac{1}{2}$. That way the probabilities work out.

Answer (score 1):

Choose a convergent increasing positive sequence, say $S_j=\sum_{1}^{j}a_i$. Then $P=m/2S_{\infty}$ where $m$ is the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}$ is a probability measure on $[-S_{\infty},S_{\infty}]$. Define $E_n=\{0\}\cup\left(\bigcup_{n}^{\infty}[S_j,S_{j+1}]\right)$ and $F_n=E_n\cup\left(\bigcup_{n}^{\infty}[-\sum_{1}^{j+1}a_i/i,-\sum_{1}^{j}a_i/i]\right)$. Obviously $1\le P(F_n)/P(E_n)\le1+1/(n+1)\rightarrow1$. Now define $A=[-S_{\infty},0]\cup\left(\bigcup_{1}^{\infty}[S_j,S_j+a_{j+1}/(j+1)]\right)$ and we have $2S_{\infty}\cdot P(A\cap E_n)=P(F_n)-P(E_n)$ and $2S_{\infty}\cdot P(A\cap F_n)=2\left(P(F_n)-P(E_n)\right)$. Hence the ratio is 2.

Comment: I don't get the 'obvious' inequality, would you give me more details?

Comment: @Snoop $P(F_n)-P(E_n)=\sum_{n}^{\infty}\frac{1}{i+1}a_{i+1}\le\frac{1}{n+1}\sum_{n}^{\infty}a_{i+1}=\frac{P(E_n)}{n+1}$